# Send XML message to SONIC JMS Queue

Tags: vb.net, jms

Im a newcomer for Sonic JSM queue. I need to send an xml message to a JSM queue. I can send a string message using following code.

```
Dim msg As Sonic.Jms.TextMessage = SonicSendSession.createTextMessage()

msg.setText(ESBMessage)

msg.setStringProperty("instance", Header)

SonicSender.send(msg, Sonic.Jms.DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT, Sonic.Jms.DefaultMessageProperties.DEFAULT_PRIORITY, MESSAGE_LIFESPAN)
```

This is working fine. But in hear this message

> Content-Type=text/plain

But I need to set it as

> Content-Type: text/xml

I can send it by following code.

```
Dim msg As Sonic.Jms.Message = SonicSendSession.createMessage()
msg.setJMSMessageID(ESBMessage)

msg.setStringProperty("instance", Header)    

SonicSender.send(msg, Sonic.Jms.DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT, Sonic.Jms.DefaultMessageProperties.DEFAULT_PRIORITY, MESSAGE_LIFESPAN)
```

But I cannot add my xml message to this msg. Im using VS 2010/VB.net.
Please help.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works in VB. But in Java it's quite easy.

What you can try is adding a new JMS header

msg.setStringProperty("Content-Type","text/xml")

or

you have to create XML message, Sonic.Jms.Ext.XMLMessage instead of Sonic.Jms.Message